# Is php notices influences to data size sending to nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, e-notices

i use nginx and php7.1-fpm.

In case when i have a bunch of notices in error log, at end i get in logs error and error 502:

> *5 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

If i increase buffers size in nginx all works well.

If i remove custom buffer settings and checkout to branch with fixed notices, all works well too.

So my question - is notices influences to data size sending from php-fpm to nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now i understand that i see notices in nginx logs. So of course its influences.